# text-shadow overwrite

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li:nth-child(even) a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red;
}

.active {
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

And second list item still have shadow. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a matter of specificity: the first rule wins because it has a bigger specificity (calculated as 1 pseudoclass and 3 elements: `13`) than the second (1 class only, no elements: `10`) : you should write instead

```
ul li:nth-child(even) a.active {
   text-shadow: none;
}
```

or - in general - any other valid rule with a specificity greater or equal than `13`.

If you cannot change the second selector you may simply use `!important` applied on the property, but its use should be limited as less as possible.

---

For further information, see also:

- this reference about the [specificity (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity);
- this article on [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) about the specificity and how to calculate it.